# web.client to download AND LOGIN from post url

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, sessionid

How can I login to a website using ASP.NET `_SessionId`

My website informations are:

`POST` method:

```
  Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=f8dSVSQCz3tJ_x3XCGq9pVaI40SZrcBxX1-S2cvo7nWTyNp-q46i7OqBoar_WIwfAFKCZORwL5TxU6XerwK7bSjyCuOZQL6kRHFtONeQblk1;
```

`ASP.NET_SessionId=kvgsffd4tjmz1qvlylomwajb`

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 176
```

`SEND`,`POST` content is:

```
__RequestVerificationToken=hWZeVXFf-I-_5JEZMMMqhcovywww8h6cTuaTwd6vsspHIU6c9958BUWNfyh1MXtEz15jhx-htav_3oV-Xn7v3u1-ysKeMgPnX_7BSs4XxBE1


&UserName=BALHBAL&Password=BLAH
```

Comment: Formatting of title and added tags.